# hide address bar while scrolling in ionic in mobile browser

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a project using Ionic and AngularJs. I need to hide the address bar on scroll just like Facebook mobile. When we open Facebook in a mobile browser and scroll to the top it hides the address bar. I need the same thing in Ionic for all platforms - Android, IOS etc.

I am breaking my head for last 2 days on this. But I  still haven't found
anything relevant. I tried many things but nothing worked out. Kindly
help me to get out of this and also suggest if it is not possible.

Comment: Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/hIzFp)

Comment: i have checked it but i need to hide the address bar in mobile browser i.e chrome, safari etc on scrolling

Comment: I don't understand. In a ionic app you cannot see the address bar. Can you post an image of what you wanna hide?

Comment: i am not using ionic app as full fledged app like watsapp rather i am using ionic app as website in browser.Please check this screen shot http://prnt.sc/cchmmi. so i want when i use ionic on mobile it should hide the address bar on scrolling like facebook mobile

Comment: You cannot hide the address bar in a mobile browser. Safari hide automatically when you scroll.

Comment: there is no way to hide it either with JavaScript ? can you please suggest me another way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try with `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui”>` or `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Comment: i will try. thank you so much for help

Comment: As @gianlucatursi already explained it's mostly up to the users browser/browser settings and you can't do much about it except try with a meta tag like proposed before which may allow hiding it in some rare cases, but still probably not only when scrolling.